# OneSignal notification to open certain activity on click

Tags: android, flutter

I checked the [Open application on notification click in OneSignal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997419/open-application-on-notification-click-in-onesignal) and [OneSignal Push Notification Click to open actiivty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014512/onesignal-push-notification-click-to-open-activity) but still not answers yet. So, I'm building a news app and integrating it with OneSignal, I'm able to receive the notification and when I clicking on it I'm getting the below JSON code

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
     this.setState(() {
  print(
 "Opened notification:
     ${result.notification.jsonRepresentation().replaceAll("\\n","\n")}");
   });
});
```

JSON Response

```
Opened notification: {
"payload": "{
"google.delivered_priority": "normal",
"google.sent_time": 1561415365754,
"google.ttl": 259200,
"google.original_priority": "normal",
"custom": "{"a":{"id":"43682"},"i":"b0f4ef57-9556-4163-9e5c-    fbcea08b4ce8"}",
"from": "800826514709",
"alert": "Test Alert",
"title": "Test Title",
"google.message_id": "0:1561415365759264%e192c215f9fd7ecd",
"notificationId": -655945385
I/flutter (30970): }",
"displayType": 2,
"shown": true,
"appInFocus": true,
"silent": null
I/flutter (30970): }
```

And the below code to capture the payload keys

```
print(result.notification.payload.jsonRepresentation());
```

JSON Response

```
{
  "google.delivered_priority": "normal",
  "google.sent_time": 1561415365754,
  "google.ttl": 259200,
  "google.original_priority": "normal",
  "custom": "{"rec":{"id":"43682"},"i":"b0f4ef57-9556-4163-9e5c-fbcea08b4ce8"}",
  "from": "800826514709",
  "alert": "Test Alert",
  "title": "Test Title",
  "google.message_id": "0:1561415365759264%e192c215f9fd7ecd",
  "notificationId": -655945385
}
```

My Question is how do I read the Key "notificationId" and "custom", I tried something like below but getting null

```
Map<String, dynamic> data =
        json.decode(result.notification.jsonRepresentation());

print(data['custom']);
```

Comment: As I see from the source code, getting **notificationId** should not be a problem: **String notificationId = result.notification.payload.notificationId;**. However there is no **custom** key in the Class file. Are you sure that it's the latest version of OneSignal SDK? You can check **OSNotificationPayload** class from the sdk source code and available variables.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your information, I've updated the thread and added the missed info at the end, regarding to the custom key, It has been added to the onesignal api for the purpose to get the Id of the news to display it, so I'm getting as it is from pushed notification from onesignal. the code is working well 
        **String notificationId = result.notification.payload.notificationId;
        print('JSON');
        print(notificationId);** but how about the custom?

Comment: Could you try like this then: **Map<String, dynamic> custom = json.decode(result.notification.payload.custom)** and then **print(custom)**?

Comment: I tried as suggest **Map<String, dynamic> custom =
            json.decode(result.notification.payload.custom);

        print(custom);** getting error: The getter 'custom' isn't defined for the class 'OSNotificationPayload'.

Comment: Had to install and configure the OneSignal SDK to test it. I don't understand, why are you using some **custom** variable in your push notification. The custom data you want to pass with your notification - should be put in to the **additionalData** parameter. After this it can be successfuly received using **result.notification.payload.additionalData**.

Comment: Good Idea, how to send PHP to onesignal? I'm using this `$data = array(
                   "id" => $_POST['news_id'],
                );
                $fields['large_icon'] = '';
                $fields = array(
                    'app_id' => "my_app_id",
                    'included_segments' => array('All'),
                    'contents' => $content,
                    'headings' => $heading,
                    'data' => $data,
                );
            //$fields['included_segments'] = array("Test Users","");
                $fields = json_encode($fields);
`

Comment: You just put a simple **single level array** in to the **data** variable when sending your request using API call. Then access it in your flutter code via **additionalData**.

Comment: As I understand from you, anything we put inside array level data in **PHP** we can read from the **additionalData** in Flutter ?

Comment: Yes. ```'data' => ['bar' => 'foo']``` will result in **additionalData** having a **Map<String, dynamic>** object with your values. Ex.: **additionalData['bar']**

Comment: I can confirm that when I used the **additionalData['id']**  it works as well, now how about when I click on the notification it only open the app and cannot do any activity

Answer (score 1):

i have this solution for you.

```
var notificationId = result.notification.payload.rawPayload["notificationId"];

Map<String, dynamic> custom = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get additional data with this:

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((openedResult) async{
var additionalData = openedResult.notification.payload.additionalData;
if(additionalData != null){
  if(additionalData.containsKey("myKey")){
    var myValue= additionalData["myKey"];
  }
 }
});
```